# Is Office 365 Personal compatible with SharePoint?

Tags: 2013, office-365

I know this may seem like a simple question:

I'm buying a new laptop and some come with a year of Office 365. I use SharePoint all the time, plus another Microsoft application called Minerva. I need to make sure the Office 365 Personal is compatible with SharePoint.

Comment: what you mean by compatibe? You mean opening the files from sharepoint to office personal?

Answer (score 1):

If you meant SharePoint is included in Office 365 Personal subscription?, No, its **NOT**

Office 365 Personal includes access to Word, Excel, PowerPoint, OneNote, Outlook, Publisher, and Access for home/non-commercial use on one computer and one Windows 8 tablet, 20 GB of additional OneDrive storage, and 60 minutes of Skype international calls per month.

[image]

Source [Office 365](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/products/buy-office-365-personal-FX104160403.aspx) and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_365)